# How to support both maven and gradle for a java SDK client project

Tags: java, maven, gradle, sdk

We are doing a java sdk client for our customers. we want to let them download it via public repository via gradle and/or maven

how do we support both? shall we create two separate projects one for gradle and one for maven? or is it possible to create only one and support both build types?

Thanks.

Comment: Is this java sdk client a kind of project template? Or a dependency?

Comment: in the end of the day the client will import this as a dependency on his gradle/maven project and will able to use this sdk's classes on his project

Comment: See https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/publishing_maven.html#publishing_maven  . Using the standard `maven-publish` Gradle plugin you can publish your artifacts to any Maven repository (it will generate the required `pom.xml` descriptor) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following your comment: If you build it either with Gradle or Maven and place the resulting jar in a Maven Repository, it can be used with both Gradle and Maven. Maven Repositories are a standard that is used by Gradle as well.